# how to use regular expression in awk or sed, for find all homopolymers in DNA sequence?

Tags: regex, awk, sed, bioinformatics, gawk

**Background**

Homopolymers are a sub-sequence of DNA with consecutives identical bases, like `AAAAAAA`. Example in python for extract it:

```
import re
DNA = "ACCCGGGTTTAACCGGACCCAA"
homopolymers = re.findall('A+|T+|C+|G+', DNA)
print homopolymers
['A', 'CCC', 'GGG', 'TTT', 'AA', 'CC', 'GG', 'A', 'CCC', 'AA']
```

**my effort**

I made a gawk script that solves the problem, but without to use regular expressions:

```
echo "ACCCGGGTTTAACCGGACCCAA" | gawk '
BEGIN{
  FS=""
}
{
  homopolymer = $1;
  base = $1;
  for(i=2; i<=NF; i++){
    if($i == base){
      homopolymer = homopolymer""base;
    }else{
      print homopolymer;
      homopolymer = $i;
      base = $i;
    }
  }
  print homopolymer;
}'
```

**output**

```
A
CCC
GGG
TTT
AA
CC
GG
A
CCC
AA
```

**question**

how can I use regular expressions in awk or sed, getting the same result ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`grep -o` will get you that in one-line:

```
echo "ACCCGGGTTTAACCGGACCCAA"| grep -ioE '([A-Z])\1*'
A
CCC
GGG
TTT
AA
CC
GG
A
CCC
AA
```

**Explanation:**

```
([A-Z])   # matches and captures a letter in matched group #1
\1*       # matches 0 or more of captured group #1 using back-reference \1
```

---

`sed` is not the best tool for this but since OP has asked for it:

```
echo "ACCCGGGTTTAACCGGACCCAA" | sed -r 's/([A-Z])\1*/&\n/g'
A
CCC
GGG
TTT
AA
CC
GG
A
CCC
AA
```

**PS:** This is gnu-sed.

Comment: yes `echo "ACCCGGGTTTAACCGGACCCAA" | grep -oE 'A+|T+|C+|G+'` works well, but, I don't know how to do it with awk or sed

Comment: @Jose is the right tool for the job in this case. It is unclear why you want to use sed or awk.

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM. `grep` is best suited for this but I've provided a  `sed` solution also.

Comment: @TomFenech you're right , I'm just learning how to use awk and sed .... and I could not do this

Comment: Yes that's right. `&` is back-reference to whatever we matched in pattern and `\n` is adding a new line after match.

Answer (score 1):

Try using split and just comparing.

```
echo "ACCCGGGTTTAACCGGACCCAA" | awk '{ split($0, chars, "")
  for (i=1; i <= length($0); i++) {
    if (chars[i]!=chars[i+1])
    {
      printf("%s\n", chars[i])
    }
   else
   { 
     printf("%s", chars[i])
   }
  }
 }' 

A
CCC
GGG
TTT
AA
CC
GG
A
CCC
AA
```

**EXPLANATION**

The split method divides the one-line string you send to awk, and separes each character in array chars[]. Now, we go through the entire array and check if the char is equal to the next One `if (chars[i]!=chars[i+1])` and then, if it´s equal, we just print the char, and wait for the next one. If the next one is different, we just print the base char, a `\n` what means a newline.

Comment: my problem is using regular expressions in awk, but thank you very much

Comment: oh i understood u wanted without them!! let me then a while!! :P